# Working with android:layout_alignStart and a real Android Device

Tags: android, xml

I am following along with a book called "Learning Android App Development" (released 6/5/13 so all examples are in date).

I am trying to align text in a relative with 8 TextViews (titled textView1 - 8) on one side (vertical orientation) and 8 to the right of each (titled dataView1-8). I wanted to have leftmargin of 36dp for the right most column of TextViews. I wanted each of the dataViews to begin their alignment from dataView1.

The code works perfectly fine in the graphical layout tab, works fine in the emulator, but not on my android device (Galaxy Note 2 - API 16).

Can you please help me get the alignment to work on my device or explain why there is even a discrepancy? Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_name_label" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_name_label"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_mass_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_marginStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/planet_mass_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_gravity_label" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_gravity_label"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_colonies_label" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_colonies_label"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_population_label" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_population_label"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_military_label" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_military_label"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_bases_label" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_bases_label"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_forcefield_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="@string/planet_forcefield_label" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could it just be my phone screen size (5.5")??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is `layout_alignStart` is supported from Android 4.2 (API level 17), but Galaxy Note II is 4.1.2 (API level 16).

If you go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignStart and change the API level (in the top left corner of the page) to 16 or lower, you'll see `layout_alignStart` entry become grayed out.

Answer (score 2):

Replace layout_alignStart with layout_alignLeft. It is supported from API level 1 and does the same thing.

Comment: Down vote - it doesn't do the same, it does the same only for LTR languages and starting API 17 , layout_alignStart should be used.